# CSS - exact same class but different background color, messes up

Tags: css, class

This is the weirdest CSS thing I have ever encountered. I cannot, for the life of me, figure it out.

Each `<span>` element gets a class assigned to it - filled with a value taken from the database. 28 of 29 go as planned - but the 29th just messes up. Adds extra margin and padding, simply breaks out of character.

Live demo: http://tf2g.com/v2/tf2g/wearable?item=demomansfro

See 'The Color of a Gentlemann's Business Pants'. It's not the length of the text next to it.. anyone?

Comment: You should make that an answer, @Adrift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is kind of amazing. Just to clarify @Adrift's point
thecolorofagentlemannsbusines`span`ts

Comment: How did I miss your post? I've seen it a couple of times, but.. how did I miss that the actual answer was in there?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the answer is because of your CSS rule:

```
.gallery-container [class*="span"] {
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

As a side note, in css, `class` is used for styles which apply to MULTIPLE elements, whereas `id` is used for SINGLE elements.

As a result, I would recommend changing your HTML/CSS to something like (I prefer the first):

**First:**
HTML

```
<li id="thecolorofagentlemannsbusinesspants">
    <span class="paint-circle"></span>
    The Color of a Gentlemann's Business Pants
</li>
```

CSS

```
#thecolorofagentlemannsbusinesspants span {
    background-color: #whatever;
}
```

OR

**Second:**
HTML

```
<li>
    <span id="thecolorofagentlemannsbusinesspants" class="paint-circle"></span>
    The Color of a Gentlemann's Business Pants
</li>
```

CSS

```
#thecolorofagentlemannsbusinesspants {
    background-color: #whatever;
}
```

Comment: You absolutely do not need to assign an ID here, a class is perfectly fine. Only use IDs to bump up your [CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/), or if a framework/library/plugin requires it, or if it makes your JavaScript easier (getElementById has higher performance, but this is negligible in the scope of most apps/sites).

Comment: But why only this one? Why not any of the others?

Comment: Also, when I disable all of the `[class*="span"]` rules, it still stands out.

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I'm an idiot. Bootstrap searches for a `span*` class, `span12` - `span1`. The Color of a Gentlemann's Busines`s pan`ts.

Great. I thought it would search for classes that start with `span`, rather than find it in the middle.